# Building tree structure from paths stored in listView

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, tree

I need to build a tree of `Named_Revision` objects (inherited from a class called `Data_Node`). The root node is of this type and called `baselineRoot`:

```
// create the baseline root node
Model.Named_Revision baselineRoot = new Model.Named_Revision(null, revisionName, true);
```

A `Named_Revision` has a constructor: `Model.Named_Revision(Model.Data_Node parent, string name, bool initialise_revisions)` `initialise_revisions` can always be assumed to be `false`. A `Named_Revision` also has a property called `timestamp`.

There is a `listView`:

[image: listView screenshot]

I want to add nodes represented by such paths to the tree structure. So, the resulting structure would be like this:

```
baselineRoot
|
inherited properties
|
type_a
/     \
type_b type_c
```

How can I achieve this? Adding the timestamps to a node is trivial. I don't mind whether it is a recursive or iterative solution.

I have a `String[]` of node names, created using `String.Split`. For instance, from the above example, there would be two arrays: `["inherited properties", "type_a", "type_b"]` and `["inherited properties", "type_a", "type_c"]`. Is there a better approach?